# Find polygon geometry of a place

Tags: python, shapefile, polygon, geometry, geopandas

I am reading in a shapefile of Metro areas in the US and then select the metro area of interest.

```
# Read shape file

px_shp = 'data/map/az/cb_2018_us_cbsa_500k.shp'

geodata = gpd.read_file(px_shp)
geodata.dtypes


# Select Phoenix-Mesa-Scottsdale, AZ

df_geodata = geodata[geodata['NAME'].str.contains('Phoenix-Mesa-Scottsdale, AZ')]
df_geodata.plot(figsize=(10, 6))
plt.title("Phoenix-Mesa-Scottsdale, AZ")
```

[image]

Now, I'd like to define the cities separately by passing the coordinates of the polygon. This means I'd have the find the boundaries of Phoenix, Mesa and Scottsdale cities. However, I cannot find a way/tool/API to obtain the polygon boundaries/geometries and pass them in.

I have looked at http://nominatim.openstreetmap.org/ which returns a collection of multipolygon in each of the cities.

```
[{"place_id":233116526,"licence":"Data © OpenStreetMap contributors, ODbL 1.0. https://osm.org/copyright","osm_type":"relation","osm_id":110815,"boundingbox":["33.277624","33.513376","-111.8939822","-111.5806478"],"lat":"33.4151117","lon":"-111.8314773","display_name":"Mesa, Maricopa County, Arizona, United States of America","class":"boundary","type":"administrative","importance":0.644252319667828,"icon":"https://nominatim.openstreetmap.org/images/mapicons/poi_boundary_administrative.p.20.png","geojson":{"type":"MultiPolygon","coordinates":[[[[-111.598158,33.45082],[-111.598195,33.45094],[-111.59823,33.451023],[-111.598257,33.451071],[-111.5983,33.45111],[-111.598342,33.451135],[-111.601778,33.451257],[-111.602976,33.451299],[-111.60446,33.451399],[-111.605305,33.451383],[-111.606666,33.4513881],
```

However, I am looking for aggregate of polygons within the multipolygon list - (POLYGON ((6065941.393835935 2104148.464510527.....)))

Ideally, I'd like a tool or an API that returns the polygon geometry based on name of the place.

Comment: what software are you using? Please update your question using  the [edit] button or add a relevant tag.

Comment: @IanTurton I am using python - geopandas, shapely libraries.